# Jshell displays mess code when invoke it from Powershell

Tags: java, jshell

I am working in Win10 build 19041 with "jshell 16.0.1”， when try to invoke interactive Jshell from command line, it display as:

```
 ~ λ jshell
|  ???? JShell -- ?? 16.0.1
|  ????????, ???: /help intro
```

What's the problem about the mess codes of "????" ?

Comment: Which terminal language does your PowerShell default to? or have you overridden any preferences for them?

Comment: ty @Naman I set Chinese as default.